# Solving a non linear system

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, hyperbolic-functions

> I have the 4 following equations.
>
> \begin{align}x^{0} &= (c + \xi^1)\sinh(g\xi^0) \\
>  x^{1} &= (c + \xi^1)\cosh(g\xi^0) \\
>  x^2 &= \xi^2 \\
>  x^3 &= \xi^3 \end{align}

I am given that $x^1 = x^3 = 0$ and $x^2 = x^0$, where $x^2$ and $x^0$ evolve with time. One can think of $x^0$ as the parameter.

Using this information, is there a consistent solution of these non linear systems of equations, given that the $\xi$ co-ordinates also change (with time)$(\dagger)$. I can't seem to find that this is the case.

$(\dagger)$ One can think that the $x^0$ coordinate is time in $x-$frame and the $\xi^0$ coordinate is the time in the $\xi-$frame.

Comment: What are the given and the unknowns ?

Comment: The $x's$ are given. What we have is that only $x^0$ and $x^2$ change, where $x^0$ is the independent parameter. Since $x^0 = x^2$, we have that the graph specifying the change in the variables in $x-$ system  is a line of slope $1$ in the four dimensional space.

Comment: Hem, what are the unknowns ?

Comment: The $\xi's$, related to the $x's$ via the equations.

Comment: Why do you provide the last two equations ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Because we're in four dimensional space. These coordinates don't change once we make the transformation.

Comment: All right, but they are already solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use

$$(x^1)^2-(x^0)^2=(c+\xi_1)^2$$ and

$$\frac{x^0}{x^1}=\tanh g\xi^0.$$

Comment: $x_1=0$ is not a concern as you can see by the full solution. This answer is correct.

Comment: Why so? See the answer above. In both equations, $x_1$ is in the denominator, which'll cause trouble.

Comment: If $x_1=0$, you necessarily have $x_0=0$. Then, $\xi_1=-c$ and $\xi_0$ is undeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

From the above set one has
$$
   \frac{x^0}{x^1}=\tanh(g\xi_0)
$$
that can be inverted using the logarithm or just formally writing
$$
   \xi_0=g^{-1}\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\frac{x^0}{x^1}\right).
$$
being $\operatorname{arctanh} (x) = \frac{1}{2}\ln \left( \frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right); \left| x \right| < 1$. Then, we just note that
$$
   \sinh(x)=\frac{\tanh(x)}{\sqrt{1-\tanh^2(x)}}
$$
and so,
$$
  \xi_1=-c+x_1\sqrt{1-\frac{x_0^2}{x_1^2}}.
$$

Comment: I am given that $x^1 = 0$. Doesn't that make both the solutions 'blow up.' Even so, we can then only pin down the values of $\xi_{0,1}$ in the asymptotic limit; they don't change (smoothly) with time as I expect from the setup of the problem.

Comment: As you can see, if you take $x_1=0$, these equations are meaningful and do not blow up just if you take also $x_0=0$. Otherwise, you will get complex values for $\xi_1$.

Answer (score 0):

With a system of nonlinear equations, any explicit solution is rare and valuable. The possibility of blowup is a small price to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Others have correct answers, but let me try to use what you know to make it even simpler.

1. $x^1 = 0$. Hence $(c + \xi^1) \cosh(g\xi^0) = 0$. Since $\cosh$ is always positive, that means that $c + \xi^1 = 0$, so $\xi^1 = -c$.
2. The first equation now implies that $x^0 = 0$.
3. Your assumption that $x^2 = x^0$ tells you $x^2 = 0$.
4. $x^3$ and $\xi^3$ can be anything. (Except that since you changed the problem, this last line no longer holds.)

Oops! I just saw that it now says $x_1 = x_3 = 0$, so the system has a solution only when $x^0 = x^1 = x^2 = x^3 =  0$. The solution is

$$
\xi^1 = -c\\
\xi^2 = \xi^3 = 0\\
$$
while $\xi_0$ can have any value.

Comment: Why the downvote? Because I showed the problem has no (nontrivial) solution? I actually answered the question asked, and gave an explicit "consistent" solution in the one case it's possible. That there's no solution in other cases is the problem's fault, not mine. :)